# Why some JSON properties will be skipped when i Import JSON inside custom connector

Tags: json, office365, powerapps, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I am building a custom connector >> and inside the Action section >> i tried to Import this JSON inside the Response :-

```
{
   "content":[
      {
         "id":1042,
         "data":{
            "beneficiary":{
               "name":"Beneficiary LTD",
               "id":1158
            },
            "pay_from":{
               "iban":"GB29OBI170000170000001",
               "accountNumber":null,
               "bic":"GB29OBI1XXX",
               "sortCode":null
            },
            "documents":{
               "PAYROLL":true
            },
            "due_date":null,
            "payment_amount":250.000000000000000000000000000000,
            "amount_due":250.000000000000000000000000000000,
            "pay_method":"MANUAL",
            "payment_reference":"Test payment reference",
            "pay_to":{
               "abartn":null,
               "iban":null,
               "accountNumber":"12345612",
               "bic":null,
               "ifscCode":null,
               "sortCode":"123456"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "id":1043,
         "data":{
            "beneficiary":{
               "name":"Beneficiary LTD",
               "id":1158
            },
            "pay_from":{
               "iban":"GB29OBI170000170000001",
               "accountNumber":null,
               "bic":"GB29OBI1XXX",
               "sortCode":null
            },
            "documents":{
               "PAYROLL":true
            },
            "due_date":null,
            "payment_amount":2501.000000000000000000000000000000,
            "amount_due":2501.000000000000000000000000000000,
            "pay_method":"MANUAL",
            "payment_reference":"Test payment reference",
            "pay_to":{
               "abartn":null,
               "iban":null,
               "accountNumber":"12345612",
               "bic":null,
               "ifscCode":null,
               "sortCode":"123456"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "id":1044,
         "data":{
            "beneficiary":{
               "name":"Beneficiary LTD",
               "id":1158
            },
            "pay_from":{
               "iban":"GB29OBI170000170000001",
               "accountNumber":null,
               "bic":"GB29OBI1XXX",
               "sortCode":null
            },
            "documents":{
               "PAYROLL":true
            },
            "due_date":null,
            "payment_amount":2501.000000000000000000000000000000,
            "amount_due":2501.000000000000000000000000000000,
            "pay_method":"MANUAL",
            "payment_reference":"Test payment reference",
            "pay_to":{
               "abartn":null,
               "iban":null,
               "accountNumber":"12345612",
               "bic":null,
               "ifscCode":null,
               "sortCode":"123456"
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "pageable":{
      "sort":{
         "empty":true,
         "sorted":false,
         "unsorted":true
      },
      "offset":0,
      "pageNumber":0,
      "pageSize":10,
      "paged":true,
      "unpaged":false
   },
   "last":true,
   "totalPages":1,
   "totalElements":3,
   "size":10,
   "number":0,
   "sort":{
      "empty":true,
      "sorted":false,
      "unsorted":true
   },
   "first":true,
   "numberOfElements":3,
   "empty":false
}
```

but I only got those properties:-

[image]

so why some properties such as "data", "Pay _from", "documents" are missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked in the swagger editor if all your parameters are present?